# How can I redirect journalctl output from a systemctl --user service to a file?

Tags: systemd, stdout, journalctl

I need to redirect systemd output (Not the binaries stdout / stderr. I mean the actual systemd output send to journalctl) to a file for a specific user unit.

I know the user can view journalctl with the following

`journalctl --follow --user -u userunit.service`

However this requires adjusting /etc/systemd/journald.conf, and adjusting storage to `Storage=persistent` and then reboot.
We cannot do this.

I know how to redirect stdout and sterr of the binary to a file. How do I redirect all journalctl output for the unit to a file of my choosing?

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

There does not seem to be a way to do this natively. Therefore I created a separate unit to perform the redirect of journalctl, the following works.

```
[Unit]
Description=redirect journalctl output for userunit to .log file

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/journalctl --follow --user -u userunit.service >> /home/user1/log/userunit.log"
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
Type=simple
    
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Just redirect the output of journalctl to a file, e.g. `journalctl --follow --since="1970-01-01 12:00:00" --user -u userunit.service > userunit.log` This will write all the logs since the beginning of time into `userunit.log` and will keep updating it continuously.

Comment: Is there a way to make systemd do this natively? Id rather not have to set up another unit/process to do this work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. After all the point of the journal is not having to deal with log files. BTW, you don't have to reboot after changing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. It's sufficient to `systemctl restart systemd-journald`

Comment: Or if `Storage=auto` you can create the directory `/var/log/journal` and then run `journalctl --flush` to write the journal to disk.

Comment: @HenriMenke re: not being able to redirect natively, understood. At this point now I am trying to create a service unit that will run this command as `ExecStart="/bin/bash -c "/bin/journalctl --follow --user -u userunit.service >> /home/user1/log/userunit.log""`
But I keep getting " Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/bash -c /bin/journalctl: No such file or directory" Any idea why?

Comment: `/usr/bin/journalctl`? Also you can't nest quotes but the outer ones are unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Did not work, keeps giving me the same error. Running the command form terminal works fine.